# Website breaking after 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Quite of a newbie question here but recently our Web Developer left our (small) company and has left us in a bind.

We recently (2 days ago) redirected our site to a newer and mobile friendly model and was working well for quite some time. For whatever reasons management deemed they needed to roll back the site to its original model and the site is breaking whenever you type in `http://www.example.com`. However, `https://` works perfectly fine, and it seems like it has something to do with the htaccess file -- but being just the project manager, coding comes second in terms of skill.

If it helps our site is `www.mauriprosailing.com` -- currently still trying to figure out why the "www" and "http" is breaking the site.

If needed I can post a .txt of our htaccess if that helps.

I appreciate all the help and apologize if this was too broad of a question!

Comment: Could you find a part of the .htaccess file that has "RewriteCond" and "RewriteRule" and post it? (If it exists, of course.)

Comment: ### Rewrite and redirect other domain aliases to mauri pro sailing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mauriprosailing.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mauriprosailing.com/blog$  [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mauriprosailing.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

Not sure if the /blog matters -- but that's what i found when looking in  the htaccess file. 

I appreciate the swift reply!

Comment: OK. Please do post your `.htaccess` into the question. ATM I'm thinking your caching (if you use it - I imagine you do) Could be breaking things. But until we see it, hard to say.

Comment: I also want to query what exactly is your issue when you say it is 'breaking'? I've gone onto your website, both `http://` and `https://` and basically what I'm seeing is an absolute explosion? Banner loads fine, then below that everything is a mess. Is this the same issue you see?

Comment: I can't guarantee that this will fix the problem, but you can try commenting out those lines (put a # before each one), and see if that fixes it. Also, I can't seem to reproduce any problem going to your site at www.mauriprosailing.com. Can you describe the problem in more detail? How is the site "breaking"?

Comment: @ArkaneMoose when I visit his site, it's an absolute explosion...

Comment: @thickguru I must not be seeing what you are seeing. Site looks completely fine for me on Firefox 47.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.docx2doc.com/download-file/UUpkC.html/59e45/0/1

Pasted full htaccess into a .txt -- thank you guys again!

Comment: Yeah its a complete explosion -- using google chrome and firefox.

Comment: @ArkaneMoose On windows, Chrome + Firefox. Explosion. Interesting that the issue is not showing on Linux.

Comment: @thickguru This is what I am seeing: http://imgur.com/gobyJtp

Comment: We use certain .css files to generate the look and feel of the website -- could it be that one of the .css files are broken/not loaded properly? 

I'm just as in the dark as everyone else -- loaded the site Friday and came into work today to find out it was recalled back to the old one and now have to attempt to fix the issue haha. I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: It's possible that the CSS isn't loading properly. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ArkaneMoose http://imgur.com/a/3p853

Comment: FWIW, both HTTP and HTTPS exhibit the same "messed up" behaviour for me. If you are seeing otherwise then you are probably seeing a cached version. Check the network traffic... "MPSTemplate.css" is getting a 404.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it seems that http://www.mauriprosailing.com/Templates/MPSTemplate.css is failing to load for you. I have no idea why it's working for me, though. If someone who is getting the broken behavior could tell me what error that is giving them, I may be able to help more. Otherwise, without any way to reproduce the problem, I most likely can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: OK, when you load https://www.mauripro.com/us/ the website works fine. It's when you remove `/us/` that it then causes it to break. However, it looks like a newer version of the website.

Comment: @thickguru Right, mauripro.com/us/ is the newer version of our current site.

Comment: Ok after inspecting the page -- it's pulling the .css file from https://www.mauripro.com/Templates/MPSTemplate.css -- is there any reason why its not calling from mauriprosailing.com?

Comment: In your code you have the following: `<link href="/Templates/MPSTemplate.css` So is this the correct css file you wanted pulling? I also ran tests on your HTML and CSS. Results: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mauriprosailing.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en and https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mauriprosailing.com%2F

Comment: @thickguru that link for the css should be correct but we have two different files for both sites. It's pulling from mauripro.com instead of mauriprosailing.com

Trying to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: So I tried to kind of put a band aid on the situation -- by copying the same css file and saving it as a different name and then asking it to pull that same file but different name, didnt work :(. It's still pulling from mauripro.com even though the new template is saved on mauriprosailing.com's server.

Comment: @rpk-mps mauriprosailing.com is now working for me. Make sure you reset your browser cache & cookies.

Comment: The issue was clearly with your old CSS file.. When I ran that test it did throw up a number of errors.

Comment: We turned off caching via development mode -- seems like it works completely fine during this time. If we turn it off, it goes back to the explosion. For whatever reason its not calling the link we desire

Comment: That narrows it. All the way back to my original thought lol.. Caching...  So when you turn caching off completely, it works fine?

Comment: Yeah lol...i just figured it out. It kind of clicked that if we turned off caching it works so i just purged all cached files on our server. A big whoosh over my head haha -- never registered it would be something so simple. Eesh! 

A big thank you to everyone who chimed in -- I appreciate it a lot and hope you all have a wonderful rest of the day! 

-rpk

Comment: That's great news! Panic over haha. Please can you post your fix as an answer and select it as correct. Will be easier than people working through all our comments if they have a similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Granted this may not apply to everyone -- but the problem was not within the htaccess file but with caching of the server. The server was not pulling the right the .css file therefore causing an "explosion" of our site and I found that purging all of cached files did the trick.